# Stripe Dotnet Checkout Session Creation for SCA

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, stripe-payments

I feel like I'm missing the obvious here. I have implemented the Checkout process using the older process of

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Basket", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"></script>
}

            //C# Controller Action
            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Submit(string shoppingCartId, string stripeToken)
            {
                ChargeCreateOptions chargeOptions = new ChargeCreateOptions
                {
                    Amount = 100* 100,
                    Currency = "GBP",
                    Description = "Some stuff",
                    ReceiptEmail = "yo@dawg.com"
                };

                //3)Make the charge
                var chargeService = new ChargeService("mySecretKey);


                    var stripeCharge = chargeService.Create(chargeOptions, null);
                    stripeResponse = stripeCharge.StripeResponse;
                    return true;

    }
```

The process above works by showing a blue Pay button and when you click it, it invokes a modal pop-up that accepts the Credit Card Details and when Submitted, hands-off to my action and makes the payment.

For the newer SCA process, it talks about creating a session and invoking the payment process through a button click that calls the following:

```
stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  sessionId: '{{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}}'
}).then(function (result) {
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
  // error, display the localized error message to your customer
  // using `result.error.message`.
});
```

I can't see how I create this {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} with the Stripe Dotnet latest version 25.7.00. Is this something that doesn't exist yet, or how does one create it?

Comment: It doesn't look like the api call to make a checkout session is available yet for the .NET SDK. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server#integrate --- for the time being, i suppose you could make this call and get the session id using a dot net http client
https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=curl

Comment: It is being worked on though : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/pull/1440 and is likely to be released in the next couple of days(Checkout is out of beta now so it will be added to the library), so I'd personally just wait for that.

Comment: Yeah I don't really want a half-and-half solution of doing the rest call "manually" to create a session token and the fulfilling the rest of the process with the library. I shall hold off

Comment: @Adrian looks like it's been released! : https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#2580---2019-04-16 The docs on stripe.com might lag a little, but you should be able to figure out usage using the [tests](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/StripeTests/Services/Checkout/SessionServiceTest.cs) in the lib